# Integrating CAS into Java Dynamic Web Project

Tags: java, tomcat, cas

**SETUP**

---

A "Hello World" servlet deployed in Tomcat (ROOT)

(1) This is working without CAS and I can access my application at the following URLs:

- http://localhost:8090/hello
- https://localhost:8443/hello

(2) I inserted the following in my Tomcat ROOT's web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.leo.Hello</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Authentication filter -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>CAS Authentication Filter</filter-name> 
    <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class> 
    <init-param> 
        <param-name>casServerLoginUrl</param-name> 
        <param-value>https://localhost:8443/cas/login</param-value> 
    </init-param> 
    <init-param> 
        <param-name>serverName</param-name> 
        <param-value>https://localhost:8443</param-value>
    </init-param> 
</filter>

<!-- Ticket validation filter -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>CAS Validation Filter</filter-name> 
    <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter</filter-class> 
    <init-param> 
        <param-name>casServerUrlPrefix</param-name> 
        <param-value>https://localhost:8443/cas</param-value> 
    </init-param> 
    <init-param> 
        <param-name>serverName</param-name> 
        <param-value>https://localhost:8443</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter> 

<!-- HTTP servlet request wrapper filter -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>CAS HttpServletRequest Wrapper Filter</filter-name> 
    <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.util.HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter</filter-class> 
</filter>

<!-- Assertion thread local filter -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>CAS Assertion Thread Local Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.util.AssertionThreadLocalFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping> 
    <filter-name>CAS Authentication Filter</filter-name> 
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping> 
<filter-mapping> 
    <filter-name>CAS Validation Filter</filter-name> 
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping> 
<filter-mapping> 
    <filter-name>CAS HttpServletRequest Wrapper Filter</filter-name> 
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CAS Assertion Thread Local Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

(3) The CAS server is also deployed within Tomcat

**PROBLEM**

---

***After all this editing, I get a 404 through both HTTP and HTTPS. What am I doing wrong here?***

***I need my application to redirect to the CAS login which would redirect back to my application on success.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) I changed Tomcat ROOT's web.xml because my application's classes are copied inside the ROOT folder and deployed from there.

(2) I came across the problem while inspecting Tomcat's and CAS server's logs. A number of logging (and some other) libraries were absent. I am listing all of them, since I don't remember the exact additions:

- commons-logging
- slf4j-api
- slf4j-ext/li>

  slf4j-jcl

  slf4j-jdk

  slf4j-log4j

  slf4j-migrator

  commons-nop

  commons-simple

(3) I do not claim to have knowledge about this specific matter, but HTTP URLs can be CASified by adding HTTP to "serverId" attribute in the following file:
***~/[CAS SERVER DEPLOYMENT DIRECTORY]/WEB-INF/classes/services/HTTPSandIMAPS-[SOME NUMBER].json***

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you are trying to casify your hello web application

I believe, to casify you application, it needs to run on secure port.

Having said that, you will be casifying the following service URL, https://localhost:8443/hello

Can you try adding the web.xml entries (CAS related) in to your hello application's web.xml instead of tomcat's ROOT web.xml?